# Getting a Netconnection.Call.Badversion when I try to connect to localhost

Tags: php, actionscript-3, apache-flex, amfphp, netconnection

Im trying to make some tests locally and I'm finding some troubles when I try to connect my AMFPHP server with Flash.

This is how I connect to my server:

```
_netConnection.connect("http://localhost/Amfphp");
```

and this is how I make a call to the predefined example service that comes with AMFPHP:

```
_netConnection.call("ExampleService.returnOneParam", res, 5);
```

(res is a Responder object)

When I try it, I get a Netconnection.Call.Badversion message.

I've googled a lot, and tried different suggestions, nothing seems to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this list: http://www.silexlabs.org/amfphp/documentation/troubleshooting-and-debugging-your-project/

The most common one I've had is if you have extra characters (even spaces or newlines) after the closing ?> tag of your php.

Also if there's an error in your code, and your php is printing that, that'll kill it as well.

Try calling it outside of flash first to make sure everything's working.

Comment: Thanks!, after going through all those items I could fix my error. I was calling "http://localhost/Amfphp" instead of "http://localhost/Amfphp/"... :P. (Note the "/" at the end of the correct url).